# How to use cross-origin cookies for server-side rendering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have a server-side rendered web app running on `localhost:3000` and the API on `localhost:3010`. How do I set the same cookie on both domains after a request to the API?

When I log in, I'm sending a POST request to `localhost:3010` and it's setting a cookie like this:

```
const token = jwt.sign({ id, email }, secret, { expiresIn });
res.cookie('authorization', token, { signed: true, httpOnly: true, maxAge: 10000000 });
```

My problem is I can't figure out how to set that cookie on the app at `localhost:3000`. I was just using localStorage before, but it doesn't work for server-side rendering when I have my API and app on different domains.

Here's how my server-side rendering middleware on `localhost:3000` looks like, trying to access said cookie:

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

export function serverSideRendering(req, res, next) {
  const cookies = new Cookies(req.headers.cookie);
  const token = cookies.get('authorization');
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure about your stack, generally speaking I solve this problem adding a proxy that groups together the resources and render / serve at the same origin just at different paths.
I.e. If you have a docker compose stack you can add a nginx layer with references to the two other containers and a configuration , if you think is worth trying I'll try to write a proper answer asap :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change property name "authorization" to "JWT-token";

```
res.cookie('JWT-token', token, { signed: true, httpOnly: true, maxAge: 10000000 });
```

or you can try native node js method;

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Set-Cookie': 'authorization='+token,
});
```

And my advice, don't use cookie, use headers fields. It's helps you in future to increase your app to ios and android apps.

And you can keep your token inside store of your app, it's more secure.

Comment: The actual cookie is sent back from the request to the API, I just can't figure out how to also set it on the other server that renders the app: https://media.giphy.com/media/1zKQ1LT3LtIcCU4TXw/giphy.gif

Comment: it's a same result if you add cookie with native method?

Comment: and i recommend you for work with cookie use storage tab in develope tool

Comment: I get what you mean. The reason I'm trying to set a cookie is because I want the server to use the token each time the browser sends a request. I can put it in the header once the JS bundle is loaded, but I can't before that, so I want to figure out how to set a cookie from a cors request.

My client requests the website from `app.com` and logs in from `api.com`, so the cookie gets set for `api.com` successfuly, I just have to figure out how to set it for `app.com`, maybe I need to do a proxy request or something.

Comment: yeah, just proxy inside nginx